# Is it good to use Heroku as a proxy?

Tags: node.js, heroku, web-scraping, proxy, ip

Heroku provides dynamic ip addresses which change when the dyno is restarted. So, instead of paying for proxies, can take advantage of this Heroku feature.

I want to do large-scale automated web scrapping without being blocked.

There already exists a Heroku app for doing exactly the above-mentioned process. But I cannot remember the name (something like this `nameOfApp.herokuapp.com`). To use it we have to do something like `https://nameOfApp.herokuapp.com/destination.com`. I came across it in a Stack Overflow question.

I predict that the domain is `anywhere.herokuapp.com` but cannot use it.

Comment: The URL you were looking https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/ but it has been restricted. Alternatively, there is another one https://cors.bridged.cc/ but it has been restricted too.

Answer (score 2):

> Heroku provides dynamic ip addresses which change when the dyno is restarted. So, instead of paying for proxies, can take advantage of this Heroku feature.

> I want to do large-scale automated web scrapping without being blocked

Heroku is unlikely to help in this regard.

For many use cases, there's never a valid reason for requests to come from cloud services. As a result, it is common for sites that don't want to get scraped to block entire IP ranges, e.g. ones for Amazon Web Services (the underlying cloud infrastructure that Heroku is built upon).

Many users find that their scrapers work fine locally, even for extended periods of time, and immediately fail when deployed to Heroku.

*Could* it help? Sure. But this will be highly dependent on the site you're trying to scrape, the mitigations in place at the time, and many other factors.

---

Side note that I'm sure you'll just ignore: please respect sites' terms of service. If they don't want you scraping them, don't scrape them. If they implement technical barriers, that's a pretty good sign that they don't want to be scraped.

Comment: I am scrapping Google search result page at the rate of around 20 requests/minute. This project is deployed in Heroku and I was blocked only 2 times in the last 3 months. When blocked I just restarted the dyno, which assigned new ip to my app. But this time I want to scrape another domain which may block me frequently. That is why I want to take precaution

Comment: I have made correction in the question. I meant "ip" and not "domain". It was a mistake. You can update your answer accordingly.

Comment: Updated, though this doesn't change much. It is still common for applications to block large ranges of IP addresses that are allocated to cloud providers.

Comment: Is it legal to scrape google search pages? Different sources give different opinions!! How to check if a website allows scraping.

Comment: @CuriousLearner, there is no single way to know what is allowed. You'll need to check on a per-site basis, usually by reading their terms of service or [searching for them](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=does+google+allow+scraping+of+search+results).